# Java generics - Class<? extends Base>

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I'm confused a bit about Java generics.
I have a class Test which extends from Base:

```
public class Test extends Base {
    private final static Test obj = new Test();

    new Auto(obj);
}
```

The constructor of Auto is like this (not my class):

```
public Auto (Class<? extends Base> programclass) {}
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
Test cannot be converted to Class<? extends Base>
```

How should I declare `obj` variable so I can pass it to `Auto` constructor?

Thanks

Comment: `Auto` wants you to pass it a `Class`, not an instance. So `obj` should actually be `private final static Class<Test> obj = Test.class;`

Comment: Aha, ok, was it. Thanks!